# Убрать выделение с EditText при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-interface

Если после изменения Edit text быстро нажать на кнопку, то после отражения фрагмента, выделение не исчезает, и этот ярлычок можно даже двигать, как избавится или снять выделение программно?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы показать курсор при нажатии на `EditText`, нужно установить слушатель касаний:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setCursorVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Чтобы убрать курсор добавьте в слушатель кнопки строчку:

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Спустя некоторое время был найден еще один метод:

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Он убирает фокус, и в целом повесив такую структуру на отражающие кнопки, удалось избавится от ярлычка поверх окон.

Comment: учтите что при таком варианте, если вы вернетесь в EditText то курсор установится в начало строки.